# How to use soft delete on belongsTo relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, soft-delete

I'm trying to implement a `belongsTo` relationship with the `->withTrashed()` scope directly on it.

This is the soft deleted model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ContractType extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

This is the model trying to access the contract types:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'contract_type_id',
        'name'
    ];

    public function contract_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ContractType::class);
    }

    public function contract_type_with_trashed()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ContractType::class)->withTrashed();
    }
}
```

This is what i get when i query these relationships:

```php
$employee = Employee::first(); // has a contract_type_id of 1
dd($employee->contract_type, $employee->contract_type_with_trashed);

/*
ContractType {#722 ▼
  #dates: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "contract_types"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
}
null
*/
```

No `ContractType` is actually deleted and the `contract_types` table does have the `deleted_at` column.

How can i get this to work ?

**[EDIT]**

This is the `contract_types` table migration:

```php
Schema::create('contract_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->tinyIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

And the `employees` table migration:

```php
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('contract_type_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('contract_type_id')->references('id')->on('contract_types')->onDelete('cascade');
);
```

As a result, i have the `deleted_at` column as expected.
I could add that doing `$employee->contract_type()->withTrashed()->get()` works well, but when it's inside the relationship, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add soft delete to your migrations? @toyi

Comment: I edited my post with the migrations :)

Comment: Just add:
`
public function contract_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ContractType::class)->withTrashed();
    }
`
Delete  ` contract_type_with_trashed()` from your model

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for those wondering, you need to include the foreign key in the belongs to relationship here, because Laravel attempts to guess the foreign key based on the method name by snake casing it and appending `_id`.

So for,

```
public function contract_type_with_trashed()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(ContractType::class)->withTrashed();
}
```

Laravel would try to retrieve the record based on a foreign key called `contract_type_with_trashed_id`

The solution is to add the foreign key as the second parameter when it does not match the method name:

```
public function contract_type_with_trashed()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(ContractType::class, 'contract_type_id')->withTrashed();
}
```